# Get xcodeproj and ruby 2.7.0 into the PATH

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, nativescript, xcodeproj

I would like to use ruby 2.7.0 and xcodeproj to get Nativescript work on macOS (version Big Sur 11.2.3).

I did a clear install on my MacBook Air 13" 2014, following this links' instructions:
https://github.com/NativeScript/docs-new/blob/develop/environment-setup.md

After all these steps NativeScript misses xcodeproj.
If i type `xcodeproj --version` into the terminal, it prints `command not found` .

Also this is my gem env dump:

```
 RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.2.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.3 (2021-04-05 patchlevel 183) [x86_64-darwin20]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/myusr/.local/share/gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby@2.7/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/myusr/.local/share/gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@2.7/2.7.3/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - x86_64-darwin-20
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
     - /Users/myusr/.local/share/gem/ruby/2.7.0
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@2.7/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

If I navigate to my xcodeproj installation:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin
```

then I run

```
./xcodeproj --version
```

it prints out the correct version of the xcodeproj installation.

Also some people suggested to check pod installation and it works fine pod --version prints it's version.

Also I got `xcodeproj (1.19.0)` in the list if I run `gem list`

How can I fix this to get the xcodeproj binary into the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to fix it with reinstalling xcodeproj and added

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin:$PATH
```

to my `~/.bash_profile`

then I opened a new terminal

Answer (score 0):

Install [Home Brew](https://brew.sh/)
Then run `brew link ruby@2.7`